# Is it possible to build an Eclipse Workspace with the command line in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven

Is it possible to generate an eclipse workspace using command line so that I can simply switch the workspace in Eclipse and everything is configured? I've already tried many approaches (using mvn eclipse:eclipse which only generates .project files but no workspaces, using the eclipse osgi jar) but I didn't get any of them to work...

Comment: Did you take a look at Eclipse Oomph? It is not maven but you can easily share eclipse settings across team members

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` should be avoided. It's been deprecated for years.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind even without Oomph, Eclipse IDE has allowed to share settings for many years: File > Export/Importt > General > Preferences.

Comment: I guess I've not made myself clear yet. I have a maven source code (multiple projects, many lines of code). I want to compile it on the server in such a way, that I can simply copy the compiled folder (including .project files) to a dev pc where the dev can click on "switch workspace" and all projects get imported without building or cleaning or doing anything else. What would you use instead of mvn eclipse:eclipse? Can't find an alternative, everything else just build the maven project in eclipse (which I don't want to since I want to do this on the server).

Answer (score 0):

mvn eclipse:eclipse is an old an deprecated command. The functionality of this and much more was replaced by Eclipse Oomph. This allows you to just define which plugins and which eclipse version you want and then on the developer computer these things could happen:

- install eclipse
- install needed plugins
- checkout the projects
- create files
- set specific eclipse settings
- build your project

I would suggest not to compile class files on a build server and move them afterwards to a developer PC. I see potential problems in debugging and profiling when the compiler is not exactly the same.

Another approach would be to create the Eclipse installation in a virtual machine (or docker container), deploy the image on the build server, build it there and then distribute the image to the developers.